# Would EMP From a Nuke Stall a car?

Tags: internal-consistency, hard-science, vehicles

In my story a man who works in Military Intel gets early warning that a nuclear attack on his base is inbound. He abandons his post, grabs his wife and kid from on base housing, and books it out of there at 90 miles per hour with 20 minutes to spare. He is 30 miles away from ground zero when the strike happens. This is far enough away that he and his family are 10 miles outside of the air blast radius. The idea is that they continue driving as far as they can before running into clogged roads or running out of gas.

My question is, does the EMP stall their car? Does EMP affect cars? I know that EMP is not the magic anti-technology ray that Hollywood makes it out to be, but I don't know what the actual real world effects on a vehicle would be.

Comment: Is there even a significant (larger than, say 5-10 miles) EMP for a "direct hit", i.e. low altitude detonation? My thinking has it that unless you _also_ do a HEMP, thanks to absorption and ionized air and all, nothing happens at 30 miles distance anyway.

Comment: @Damon that's what I am seeing - gamma ray deposition is limited to 10 miles in low atmosphere.  This article http://ece-research.unm.edu/summa/notes/SDAN/0032.pdf referenced from the Wikipedia entry on Nuclear EMP has the maths for Surface Burst EMP specifically on p4 of the pdf, but I don't have the time to re-educate myself on the maths to write a full answer - best wishes if you do

Comment: Glad to see that the site has finally loosened up its definition of world building.  I asked [a very similar question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35789/is-outrunning-a-nuclear-mushroom-cloud-feasible) 2.5 years ago and it got  closed as off topic.

Comment: You should read One Second After, by John Matherson. It delves into many aspects of an EMP attack, including the effects on cars

Comment: I don't have the numbers on hand to form a proper answer, but I doubt it. I once worked on a project to make a remote car disabler (idea was for police to use in a chase) and it was remarkably hard to shut off engines with EM interference. We were able to do it, but had to place a powerful emitter right up against the target car. Obviously an EMP from a nuke is much more powerful, but inverse-square is also a b*tch.

Comment: @HenryTaylor -- don't be surprised if this one gets nominated. It's not worldbuilding related either!

Comment: @elemtilas, I still stand by my original assertion (from back in 2016) that ground zero of a nuclear blast is a science fiction world, in the same way that the bridge of a star ship can be a world.  In both cases, they are the setting upon which a work of fiction is told.  An author struggling to understand the complexities of his characters facing hot winds and fallout is having exactly the same challenges that an author working out the details of any world they have never lived in.  And those exact challenges are what this site strives to help solve.

Comment: @HenryTaylor -- sure. If that blast happened *within a SF world*. As it stands, this is simply a real-world question with no worldbuilding context. This is just DC  with a bit of bomb damage. A bridge of a starship is obvious worldbuilding context. Because: starships, interstellar travel, spacefaring cultures, aliens, etc. Authors struggling to understand the effects of EMP would naturally research those effects in an appropriate forum. This is why authors write to & work with scientists, detectives, museums, physicians, etc. If this author has a *worldbuilding* query, we're the place to ask!

Comment: @elemtilas, unless it is a historical narrative set in 1945 japan, any work of fiction where a bomb goes off near an occupied automobile IS SCIENCE FICTION.   Such an environment is world building simply because it doesn't exist in the real world and the answers sought by such science fiction authors may exceed the kind of advice which scientists, detectives and other experts can offer.  They may be looking for more than hard facts; looking for exactly the kind of speculative imagining which the members of world building do so well.

Comment: @HenryTaylor -- No, I don't buy that argument at all. That's just -- *at best* -- ordinary fiction. As such, it is clearly off-topic here.

Answer (score 62):

## Depends on the car

It also depends on luck, sometimes an EMP will do permanent damage, sometimes it won't. The chances are you'll blow a bunch of fuses at the very least.

If you're running a diesel then it'll probably keep going. Not because the electronics are any more robust but because diesel doesn't actually need the glow plugs, it'll run on compression ignition. Depending on which fuses you blow, it may not start again if you stop the engine. If you fry the engine management system it'll run less efficiently, but it'll keep going. I once had a modern diesel running without fuel pumps, without glow plugs, without engine management, and only 3/4 cylinders, diesels keep going.

For petrol cars, the more modern and high spec the car, the more damage it's at risk of taking. If you're talking about a new BMW or Mercedes there's a reasonable chance it'll be completely knocked out from permanent damage to delicate electronics and drive by wire systems. Almost nothing you're holding is directly connected to the vehicle control it represents, it all goes through the computer first, even the steering.

If you're talking something from the 1970s with minimal electronics and all the refinement of a cart, it may even keep going with a brief cough as it cuts out during the pulse and then bump starts itself from the momentum.

---

## Of course you're not the first to consider this issue.

The [EMP Commission](http://www.empcommission.org/) (appears legitimate) have [written a report](http://www.empcommission.org/docs/A2473-EMP_Commission-7MB.pdf) that includes considering the damage to vehicles from EMP which implies that there's no real issues.

However it should be noted that this report only covers vehicles up to 2002, current high spec vehicles have a far higher level of "drive by wire" computer control.

*From page number 115 (pdf page 131)*

> We tested a sample of 37 cars in an EMP simulation laboratory, with automobile vintages ranging from 1986 through 2002. Automobiles of these vintages include extensive electronics and represent a significant fraction of automobiles on the road today. The testing was conducted by exposing running and nonrunning automobiles to sequentially increasing EMP field intensities. If anomalous response (either temporary or permanent) was observed, the testing of that particular automobile was stopped. If no anomalous response was observed, the testing was continued up to the field intensity limits of the simulation capability (approximately 50 kV/m).
>
> Automobiles were subjected to EMP environments under both engine turned off and engine turned on conditions. No effects were subsequently observed in those automobiles that were not turned on during EMP exposure. The most serious effect observed on running automobiles was that the motors in three cars stopped at field strengths of approximately 30 kV/m or above. In an actual EMP exposure, these vehicles would glide to a stop and require the driver to restart them. Electronics in the dashboard of one automobile were damaged and required repair. Other effects were relatively minor.  Twenty-five automobiles exhibited malfunctions that could be considered only a nuisance (e.g., blinking dashboard lights) and did not require driver intervention to correct.  Eight of the 37 cars tested did not exhibit any anomalous response.
>
> Based on these test results, we expect few automobile effects at EMP field levels below 25 kV/m. Approximately 10 percent or more of the automobiles exposed to higher field levels may experience serious EMP effects, including engine stall, that require driver intervention to correct. We further expect that at least two out of three automobiles on the road will manifest some nuisance response at these higher field levels. The serious malfunctions could trigger car crashes on U.S. highways; the nuisance malfunctions could exacerbate this condition. The ultimate result of automobile EMP exposure could be triggered crashes that damage many more vehicles than are damaged by the EMP, the consequent loss of life, and multiple injuries.

Comment: The spark plugs will fire regardless, so whlie this may not halt the car, when fired at the improper moment, it may stall the car significantly.  If the car recovers from the stall, it would run until the car is turned off.  At that point, it may or may not be able to start again, even if the car was made during the 1970s.

Comment: @Neil, diesel engines do not have spark plugs. And after a nuke particulate pollution is not a major concern.

Comment: @L.Dutch True, but OP was clearly asking about cars in general, not specifically diesel cars.

Comment: Apparently computerized fuel injection systems significantly pre-date the date of this report; I was a little surprised by that.  Certainly cars contain much more sophisticated electronics now.  Buried in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OobLb1McxnI you will find out that the reason they could make their hack work over the internet is that all the vehicles with this system have a connection to the Verizon mobile phone network.

Comment: @DaytonWilliams, that's a classic case of *The 'S' in 'IoT' stands for security*.

Comment: [This report](https://www.ferc.gov/industries/electric/indus-act/reliability/cybersecurity/ferc_meta-r-320.pdf) from 2010 also suggests that cars should mostly survive, and though it posits that that might change, it places more blame on potential use of non-metallic materials, rather than increased use of computers.

Comment: A few considerations which will be very important are: the height at which the nuke went off, it's yield, and it's intent. If it was low-yield weapon, detonated relatively close to the earth's surface and your protagonist is on the other side of the Rockies, then most of the primary EMP effects wouldn't be in play. If it was a purpose built EMP weapon detonated high in the atmosphere, then field strengths could certainly approach the numbers used in the testing Separatrix references if you're only 30 miles out from GZ.

Comment: @Cadence, Though they put it in the myths section (untested) saying cars have short wiring, but the average modern car has about a mile of wiring, compared to 150ft in 1950, so they could be wrong on that, I'd rather see it tested again. The rest of the myths section there is very interesting, especially the yield being largely irrelevant.

Comment: Current cars have higher dependence on board computers. Very few currently produced cars will start with a defect in the board computer. Car keys that depend on electronics to verify key authenticity using RFID (many keys nowadays, especially in cars with a start button instead of a normal contact) are especially likely to fail, because these keys can't be shielded. For some cars (Tesla for example), there's a hidden keyhole to be able to enter the car with either key or car battery dead, but this doesn't allow starting the car.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the steering has to be connected to the wheels somehow, so that a minimal amount of steering is possible even if power and electronics are lost.

Comment: @Arsenal That is correct, along with brakes, in every major manufacturer of cars which I am aware.

Comment: I would add something about electric cars aswell

Comment: @Reed, I know very little about electric cars in terms of the engineering, but somehow I suspect that the amount of internal electrical noise they normally generate will mean that everything is more heavily shielded to protect it from itself, and hence it may be completely unaffected.

Comment: @Separatrix Interesting thought, but as an electrical engineer, I can state that the type of noise generated by an EMP and that generated by the motors in an electric car are vastly different, so any extra shielding or other type of noise mitigation will not have a large impact. If the EMP voltage density was such to create problems in a non-electric car, chances are very good that those same circuits would be similarly impacted in an electric car. In fact, there are probably more electronics in the electric car which could potentially be fried.

Comment: Do note that how well grounded the car is will also make a significant difference. There is enough metal surrounding the delicate electronics to provide at least a little energy absorption if the body is grounded. Someone who knew an attack was coming could take advantage of this. Disconnecting the battery so that the electronics were completely powered off would also help to limit secondary damage from unsynchronized circuit activation and memory corruption in any microprocessors.

Comment: Not quite on diesels. You're correct that they don't need spark plugs, so given a fuel supply they'll run on their own. However the fuel pump is almost always electrical (running in a closed loop with a pressure sensor to maintain a constant rail pressure), and if the engine management dies then so too does your fuel pump.

Comment: Side note: old cars like a VW Beetle (the post war ones, not the new ones), are pretty much immune to EMP as they use mechanical devices to trigger the sparkplugs.

Comment: The three cars that experienced an engine stall wouldn't necessarily glide to a halt.  Many of them, particularly those with manual transmissions, would naturally restart themselves because the forward motion of the vehicle, without the clutch engaged, will continue to spin the crankshaft until the sensors on the ECU work out what they're doing and the injectors and spark plugs cut back in again.

Answer (score 9):

One other consideration is the car in the line of sight of the nuclear blast at detonation or not.  Estimating a Nuclear Bomb's destructive capacity is a very imprecise science.  For example, the Nagasaki device (Fat Man) was theoretically more destructive than the Hiroshima device (Little Boy).  In reality, the reverse was observed.  This was because Little Boy was detonated over what was an open field with little to stop the destructive forces of the bomb.  Fat Man detonated below the mountain tops of a valley, which contained much of the destructive energy of the blast to the valley's sparing the bulk of the city, which could still witness the destruction.

The destructive portion of the bomb's blast are light/heat radiation and the over-pressure.  In order, you will first see the light, then feel the heat, and then see the overpressure.  The former two are near instantaneous.  if you are in line of sight, I personally call this the "Simba's Kingdom Fire" because everything that the light touches will burst into flames.  The closest known survivor to Hiroshima Ground Zero was in a bank vault at the time of the raid and was not exposed to the light/heat as the rest of the bank became engulfed in an inferno and then blown away.  It's distance to GZ was measured in meters.  The overpressure will be felt at progressively larger time gaps from ground zero.  An air burst is more destructive than a ground burst because there is little to stop this, though the destruction of most of Nagasaki was prevented by obustructions that contained the blast, the affected industrial area was absolutely destroyed.  Meanwhile, damage from the light at radiation at Hiroshima could be traced all the way to a grove of trees on a hill overlooking the Jinkaku-ji Temple in Kyoto... a distance of 361.2 km (225 miles) from ground zero.

This is true of the EMP as it is line of sight only... it was believed that a full on Soviet nuclear war would start with a very high altitude burst over the continental US... high enough that no target is damaged... but almost every electronic device is put out of commission on the North American Continent.  The car may however still survive if something was obstructing line of sight from the blast.  Being under a tunnel might give you the chance to get out of the way... the EMP in a full on attack on the US will normally proceed the attack's more destructive capability.  A closer to earth air burst will likely be safe if he is safe from the light/fire destruction.

Comment: "Simba's Kingdom Fire" is such a cheerful name for something so abjectly horrifying.

Comment: Your answer is a little wrong -- it's not _anything in line of sight_. Detonate an EMP high enough and, no matter what it sees, it won't do jack to the things below; it dissipates before it can hit the ground. The reason high-altitude nukes generate such massive damage isn't that they have line-of-sight on everything, it's that the comparatively small EMP creates a much, much bigger one in the atmosphere. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-altitude_nuclear_explosion#EMP_generation).

Comment: Extremely intense light can also mess with electronics in interesting ways ... though most of the stuff in a car is in rather thoroughly opaque housings...

Comment: @NicHartley:  Thank you.  The Lion King is always on my mind in Nuclear Bomb discussions because you are almost required to say "everything the light touches" to describe what catches fire.  Further tying it to such a well known movie really helps get the point across.

Comment: Not quite.  Non conductors don't do much to block EMP.  So a plywood and shingle roof doo little, while a tin roof may help a lot.

Answer (score 7):

### Powertrain: Dumb luck will be the ruling factor

It's all going to depend on the luck of the draw and how the hit occurs and how EMP waves bend around local terrain and the metalwork of the particular car.

First, remember the powertrain is *already substantially inside a Faraday cage*.  The hood is metal, the unibody is metal and so is the engine - this largely wraps the engine package.

Nonsense to dismiss: that some cars are "mechanical" and will Just Keep Working.  Nosirree. Every modern car is [FADEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FADEC).  Even the diesels, *remember when [VW cheated the Smog tests](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-34324772) by detecting when the car was on a test stand and detuning the engine during those times*?  The only way to do that is with FADEC.  All the other builders who were not cheating also required FADEC.  **So all modern cars are computer *controlled***.

I.E. the computer decides when (i.e. which microseconds) the fuel injector fires, and it does this in real-time on the fly.  If the computer gets borked, the car doesn't stay at the last throttle position, **it simply forgets to inject fuel** starting right now, so the engine dies instantly.

The days of there being a basically mechanical carb/FI system with computers "only doing trim optimization" started in the 1970s with carburetors, and ended in the early 1990s -- killed off dead in 1996 when OBDII became law.  OBDII requires FADEC.

But even in 1991 you'd be hard pressed to find a non-FADEC engine, probably in a light truck.  Why?  It's a darn good technology that makes engines run better, *much* longer, and more powerful too, by enabling *other* performance tech.

### Older automobiles are practically extinct *on the road*

The current mix of automobiles found on the highway contain essentially zero pre-FADEC era cars.  You might find older trucks without FADEC, the bigger the more likely, but only up to a certain size.

California has achieved a practical peace with classic car lovers, based on the following fact: **There aren't enough of them left to make a difference**.  No, I mean there are loads. **But they're not daily drivers**.  They run so rarely that they don't have a significant impact.  Simply put, they're not worth regulating.

As an author, that means *if* you prioritize a search for an EMP-proof car, look for well-cared-for but rarely-driven collector cars. *You won't find one in an office parking lot, though*.  It'll be in an enthusiast's garage.  Or out back up on blocks, but that one won't run.

### Creature comforts: All bets are off

Powertrain computers on modern cars are *already* extremely hardened - not against EMP but just against *failing generally*. Some fool shorting an oxygen sensor to 12V, a wiring harness meltdown in transmission control wiring, whatever.  That's powertrain.

Now modern cars have **a whole second *tranche** of computers in the carbody, and those don't run the powertrain, they run the human/creature comforts.  For instance the left door has 1 power window motor and *Four* power window switches.  14 wires? Not anymore, now it's 2 power/ground wires, and two thin little signal wires, and embedded computers in every door that chat over the signal wires.

And in recent years, as you well know, this "body-side" stuff has *exploded* to be *the reason you buy a car* - built in Nav, Siri, Alexa, smartphone integration, your music, Sirius Radio, all the smart-car stuff potentially including the autopilots - some cars *more than 50% of the cost of the car is in this consumer-appeal electronic cruft*.

This stuff is all body-side, and there are places where the body is not steel, **but the dash and door panel interiors are not steel at all**. EMP will ignore all that and reflect in unpredictable ways off the parts of the car which are metal, exposing the body-side stuff to a lot of potential damage.

So there's a pretty good chance that your engine will work but your speedo will not. Sirius works but ONStar does not, turn signals fail, and you can't roll down your windows.  And the A/C won't turn on because the sophisticated comfort control took a hit, that doesn't doom you, but the fan won't run either, *and that dooms you*.

Ever drive a car with no fan and no windows in the summer? You cook.  It's the same exact physics as dogs and babies dying from being abandoned in the car, except you happen to be moving.

However if the blower works, and a smart person could "jumper it so it's hard on" depsite blown electronics, that makes the car interior livable - though if it's a sunny day over 60F, you *will* need quite a bit of hydration, solar load beats you up bad.  Actually for best freeway fuel economy you want windows up, A/C off, blower on max.  "Windows down" is bad due to aero-drag, and A/C on takes a lot of fuel.

Comment: Would this actually lock the passengers in? I'd think doors must be openable mechanically from the inside, but at least on the rear it's common to have electronic child locks. Ventilating the car by pushing the doors open a little works quite well, albeit with very turbulent draft.

Comment: @leftaroundabout doors that don't work from the inside is a feature that is exploding. It used to be a special order as part of a police car package. Now most newer family cars have a switch in the jamb, and it's often on without the driver realizing, just a "quirk of the car". Smash the window is easy, and pull the outside handle, but if the power lock was snapped shut at EMP time, that won't work.   So you climb out the window, shattered temp glass is pretty harmless.  It's designed to be harmless.

Comment: @Harper, they might not have a little metal button to pull up on the top of the door to unlock the door, but every new car that I have owned does have a mechanical lever that unlocks the door.  I don't have a reference, but I'm pretty sure a car that could possibly lock you inside due to electrical failure would probably fail some pretty basic safety tests.

Comment: @JPhi1618 perhaps you did not have family cars, or, like many drivers are simply unaware of the jamb switch which disables that. Heck most don't even know how their shifter interlock actually works.   I am mainly referring to rear doors in family cars (and before that police cars) where, yes, Virginia, the *specific design purpose* is to render rear seat occupants unable to escape the vehicle.  Of course you can *always* bust out glass in a real pinch, so "unable" is too strong a word.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to be concerned about, EMP and nuclear radiation.  Both will affect the engine.

At the distance you are talking about, the mechanical parts of a car are unaffected by nuclear radiation or EMP.  The only part of the engine that is affected is the electronics.

**EMP**

One thing to consider is that the body of most cars is metal and forms a Faraday cage around the engine and all its electronics.  The shell of the car will provide a lot of shielding from E-field components of the EMP.  If the shell happens to be steel (as in an older car) then it will also provide H-field shielding.

For EMP specifically, there is a momentary voltage gradient throughout the space of the car.  it can look like a voltage is applied on various points (according to the field gradient in the pulse).  Note that the smaller the distance the smaller that voltage will appear.

The copper wiring in the car is not directly damaged by radiation or EMP.  But it can act as an antenna that can gather energy and put it into circuit cards, where it can do damage.

Most modern electronics include ESD protection devices in nearly every microchip.  There is also power supply capacitors on each circuit card.
All of the power supply capacitors and ESD devices will actually try and locally absorb the EMP.

For highly miniaturized electronics (like integrated circuits) the effect can be quite small and won't directly do much damage.  Modern CMOS integrated circuits contain opposing pairs of transistors between power and ground.  Normally only one of each pair is on.  But when exposed to EMP induced voltages both can turn on, causing a short between power and ground, which can destroy the chip.

For the most part, the destructive energy that kills electronics exposed to EMP comes not from the radiation itself, but rather from the batteries or AC outlets that power those electronics.  Turning off the car and disconnecting the battery will drastically reduce the damage.

**NUCLEAR RADIATION:**

The fiberglass material that the circuit cards are made from is immune.  As well as the copper traces and planes that form the connections in the circuit cards.  Ceramic capacitors and film resistors are largely unaffected.

The only items that are really affected by nuclear radiation are semiconductors (diodes, transistors, integrated circuits).  When particle radiation from an atomic detonation hits semiconductors it causes them to conduct.  For diodes, the reverse leakage current increases.  For transistors, they can become turned on.  Unless the exposure is at a very high does rate, or for a very long time the effects will disappear once the radiation disappears.

Modern CMOS integrated circuits contain opposing pairs of transistors between power and ground.  Normally only one of each pair is on.  But when exposed to radiation both can turn on, causing a short between power and ground, which will destroy the chip.

With respect to the radiation, if you simply remove power from the device, then its likely that it may not suffer damage.  In general electronics are usually only damaged by nuclear radiation when they have power applied.  For the most part, the destructive energy that kills electronics exposed to radiation comes not from the radiation itself, but rather from the batteries or AC outlets that power those electronics.

If you knew when the blast was about to happen, then just stop the car, pop the hood, and disconnect the battery.  Once the EMP has passed, reconnect the battery and you should be OK.